# Uncaught TypeError: function () { [native code] } is not a constructor

Tags: angular, angularjs, typeerror

he tratado de actualizar de angular 7 a angular 8 siguiendo las directrices del angular.update. Por lo que veo no tiene muchos cambios de esa version. En mi package.json se ha subido bien la version aqui lo muestro :

```
"name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "package": "cat dist/angular6-elements/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js | gzip > elements.js.gz && ls -lah elements.js.gz",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/elements": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.2.1",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "custom-elements-es5-adapter": "^1.0.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.12",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
```

He probado a cambiar la version de node con el comando `NVM` pero parece que ese no es el problema. Con el comando `npm start`, compila bien, pero a la hora de llamar el `localhost:4200` da el error que pongo en el titulo.

```
   Uncaught TypeError: function () { [native code] } is not a constructor
    at SockJSClient.<anonymous> (SockJSClient.js:18:245)
    at new SockJSClient (SockJSClient.js:42:1)
    at initSocket (socket.js:20:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (client:176:1)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node (vendor.js:153593:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at 0 (environment.service.ts:11:32)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
```

La aplicacion es una aplicacion super sencilla que solo tiene un index y poco mas